# Object disappears in Bucket, (Autodesk forge)

Tags: autodesk-forge

Objects (files) disappears in Buckets after a day. The translated data is still there since I immediately get "success" on the translation status if I upload the same file again.

Is there some time-limit param? Can't find any https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you get the details of the bucket using the following URL:
    https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/:bucketKey/details

Take note of the property `policyKey`, I got a hunch that if you have been following the autodesk tutorials, you have created a bucket with `transient` `policyKey` which marks all model that have existed for 24 hours for deletion.

Extra note: files that are marked for deletion are not immediately deleted based on my past experience.

See also:
Bucket retention policy: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/
Creating a bucket: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-POST/
^Take note of `policyKey` in the request body